# change function to a class with method for setting input variables of function

Tags: c++, api-design

I am writing an **API** for my library. I have a function that takes 5 classes as inputs :

```
result func(A a,B b,C c,D d,E e);
```

I want to change it to a class that takes the inputs one by one and then the class can be execute when all inputs set :

```
class func
{
void setA(A a);
void setB(B b);
.......
result execut();
}
```

i want to know this is a bad idea ?

Comment: It's a very useful thing at times, although now that C++ has closures (lambda syntax) those times are much less frequent than they used to be.

Comment: It's fine, but keeping the function as a free function and packing the parameters in a struct accomplishes effectively the same thing and is often preferable. It depends on the situation though.

Comment: Honestly, this is what C99's designated-initializers are designed for. GCC has supported one syntax in C++ for eons, so most people use them even though they're not standard. Keep in mind that leaving some value as default is often desirable.

Comment: thanks for your feedback

Comment: Chandler Carruth gave a presentation which explicitly mentions the new piece of code as ruining the compilers ability to optimize. (https://youtu.be/FnGCDLhaxKU at 1h30)

Comment: Are A, B, C, D, E optional/defaulted ?

Comment: @Jarod42 not optional or defaulted

Comment: So having setter seems the wrong choice. Either provide them to constructor, or in the execute method directly. (So user cannot miss a field, and you don't have to handle missing fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not bad idea to make a class from my function, even if later i find that the function is a better choice, i can write a helper function over of my function class like this:

```
result Func(A a,B b,C c,D d,E e)
{
func f;
f.setA(a);
f.setB(b);
......
return f.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea. Because after rewrite your code you can make unit-tests much easier for this class.

Comment: I don't see how `result func(a,b,c,d,e);` is more complicated to test than `func f; f.setA(a); f.setB(b); f.setC(c); f.setD(d); f.setE(e); f.execut()`. You even add more pathological cases to test in the second case (missing arguments).

Comment: Well I can't write good unit-tests when a function has more then three arguments. Sometimes a complexity may be high. Of course if the function is mathematical then it is ok.

Comment: About **pathological cases to test in the second case (missing arguments)**. Yes this is true. You are right.